# How can I create a Bezier curve which an object can follow? Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bezier

I want to create a Bezier curve within a script from given points and have an object follow said path.

I have tried using Sebastian Lague's path creator and my problem with it is figuring out how to create the curve from within a script. My attempt of doing that is shown below but on start the object just flies into oblivion.

```
using PathCreation;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PathCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    VertexPath path;
    Vector3[] points = new Vector3[5];

    public EndOfPathInstruction end;
    public float speed;
    float dstTravelled;

    void Start()
    {
        points[0] = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        points[1] = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);
        points[2] = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 2f);
        points[3] = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 3f);
        points[4] = new Vector3(2f, 0f, 3f);

        path = GeneratePath(points, true);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        dstTravelled += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = path.GetPointAtDistance(dstTravelled, end);
        transform.rotation = path.GetRotationAtDistance(dstTravelled, end);
    }

    VertexPath GeneratePath(Vector3[] points, bool closedPath)
    {
        BezierPath bezierPath = new BezierPath(points, closedPath, PathSpace.xyz);
        return new VertexPath(bezierPath, transform, 0.1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stopping the object from moving?  Newtons First Law says : An object at rest stays at rest and an object in motion stays in motion with the same speed and in the same direction unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.

Comment: @jdweng when I create the BezierPath, the bool value 'ClosedPath' is set to true, creating a loop, the object should be travelling through each point in the array across a smooth Bezier path, according to the documentation provided by Sebastian.

Comment: "ClosedPath" is going to create a curve that is closed so the end and start points meet.  You do not want a closed path.

Comment: Unity has a built-in Splines package along with pre-made Bezier curves:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.splines@1.0/manual/getting-started-with-splines.html